# Google Play Console Store Analysis report via Python

Tags: python, performance, google-play, store, google-play-console

I'm trying to fetch the store performance analysis report via google API through python and throwing me an error.
I follow the process that is present in the [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?hl=en#zippy=%2Cdetailed-reports%2Caggregated-reports%2Cdownload-reports-using-a-command-line-tool%2Cdownload-reports-using-a-client-library-and-service-account%2Csee-an-example-python%2Cstore-performance-new-export-available-march%2Cinstalls).

I'm trying to see this error where it is not able to found this.
NotFound: 404 GET [https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/[publisher_bucket_id]/o/stats%2Fstore_performance%2Fstore_performance_{packageName}_202304.csv?alt=media](https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/%5Bpublisher_bucket_id%5D/o/stats%2Fstore_performance%2Fstore_performance_%7BpackageName%7D_202304.csv?alt=media): No such object: [developer_bucket_id]/stats/store_performance/store_performance_{packageName}_202304.csv: ('Request failed with status code', 404, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>, <HTTPStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT: 206>)

Can someone help me with this issue how to resolve this error?
or what steps need to be taken care of.

Answer (score -1):

1. Double-check that you have specified the correct bucket ID and file path.
2. Verify that the object you are trying to access actually exists in the specified location.
3. Ensure that you have the necessary permissions to access the object.
4. Check if there are any issues with the API itself or with the network connection